# mysqli transaction/savepoint functions vs. manually using query()

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, mariadb

Do the following two pieces of code work identically, or do the native `mysqli` transaction functions do some extra stuff?

I'm particularly interested in how errors are handled and reported (if at all) when starting and committing transactions/creating and releasing savepoints.

**Using specific `mysqli` functions for transaction handling:**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'batman', 'batcave');
if (!$db->begin_transaction()) { throw new Exception($db->error); }
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="apple"');
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="banana"');
if (!$db->savepoint('vegetables')) { throw new Exception($db->error); }
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="potato"');
exc_query('DELETE FROM utility_belt WHERE item="turnip"');
if (!$db->release_savepoint('vegetables')) { throw new Exception($db->error); }
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="orange"');
if (!$db->commit()) { throw new Exception($db->error); }
```

**Using plain old `query` function to do the same thing:**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'batman', 'batcave');
exc_query('START TRANSACTION');
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="apple"');
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="banana"');
exc_query('SAVEPOINT vegetables');
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="potato"');
exc_query('DELETE FROM utility_belt WHERE item="turnip"');
exc_query('RELEASE SAVEPOINT vegetables');
exc_query('INSERT INTO utility_belt SET item="orange"');
exc_query('COMMIT');
```

**Implementation of `exc_query` function used above:**

```
function exc_query($q) {
    global $db;
    if (!$db->query($q)) {
        throw new Exception($db->error);
    }
}
```

**Why am I asking?**

I'm occasionally getting issues when trying to do `RELEASE SAVEPOINT <name>`, and seeing `SAVEPOINT <name> does not exist`, even though I'm certain I have previously sent `SAVEPOINT <name>` to the server.

Based on what I've read in [MariaDB's documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/savepoint/), this error could be thrown if the intitial `START TRANSACTION` failed in my examples. In that case, a transaction wouldn't be started, therefore `SAVEPOINT <name>` would be silently ignored, but `RELEASE SAVEPOINT <name>` would subsequently throw an error.

What makes me wonder is that the following line doesn't catch any failures to create the create the initial transaction in these cases:

```
if (!$db->query($q)) {
    throw new Exception($db->error);
}
```

... so I'm not sure if I'm right or not. Unfortunately, the official PHP documentation on how those mysqli functions work is [not](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) [very](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.savepoint.php) [helpful](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.release-savepoint.php).

Comment: Can you clarify which of the two versions is giving your these errors? I suspect it is the latter (direct queries), but it isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, the second version, just using `query()`, is the version we're currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli_nonapi.c#L1115:

```
static int mysqli_savepoint_libmysql(MYSQL * conn, const char * const name, zend_bool release)
{
    int ret;
    char * query;
    unsigned int query_len = spprintf(&query, 0, release? "RELEASE SAVEPOINT `%s`":"SAVEPOINT `%s`", name);
    ret = mysql_real_query(conn, query, query_len);
    efree(query);
    return ret;
}
```

PHP just sends the exact same query to the database, and doesn't so anything else.

As for why `MySQLi::savepoint()` would work any different from `MySQLi::query("SAVEPOINT")`, I have no idea. The error handling inside the PHP source seems to be the same, so I would expect the result of your `$db->query($q)` to be `false` if something goes wrong.